# Oracle Apex Restful Services VS Code

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created Oracle Apex free account using link https://apex.oracle.com/en/
I have created tables and configured restful services for table. I can do get calls to API end point from Postman web as well as client version, but when I try to run python code in VS Code, I don't get any response back.

```
import requests

url = "https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/my_workspacename/sample/"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer token_copied_from_postmn',
  'Cookie': 'copied_from_postman'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used HTTP client instead of Requests